# Show validation on each UItextfield after tapping submit button using RxSwift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, rx-swift

I am new to RxSwift and MVVM pattern, I would like to ask how do I show validation on each UItextfield after tapping submit button using RxSwift.

Answer (score 0):

Your view model should have an `Observable<Bool>` for each text field. It if emits false then the data in the field is invalid. These `Observable<Bool>`s should emit  values every time the button's tap Observable triggers.